# How to set TCPListener to always listen and when new connection discard current

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcplistener, networkstream

I want to admit I'm not the strongest in c# and I have developed this program by looking at several tutorials, I would appreciate a lot if you can be detailed in your answer.
I would like my TCP Server to always listening for incoming connections and when a new TCP Client connects, I want it to discard the old connection and use the new one.

I have tried to implement this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/19387431/3540143
but my issue is the fact that when I'm simulating a TCP client, but somehow the answer above will only receive one message (my current code receive all messages sent), also I've tried to convert the data over so I receive it in same way as the code below but without any success.
Also the code above I believe is just accepting new clients, without discarding the previous connected clients.

My current code, which can handle a connection and search for new connection once a disconnection have been made, I want to make it so I'm always looking for new connection and if a new client want to connect I'm discarding the current to let the new through

```
public class TCPListener
{
    public static void Listener()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on carPort.
            Int32 port = 5002;

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                // Get a stream object for reading
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
                }
                // Shutdown and end connection
                Console.WriteLine("Client close");
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            Console.WriteLine("Stop listening for new clients.");
            server.Stop();
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If anyone needs the solution for my issue then this is how the code looks like when I applied what Cecilio Pardo suggested, which works really great!

```
public class TCPListener
{
    Form form = new Form();
    public static void Listener()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on carPort.
            Int32 port = 5002;

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                data = null;
                bool dataAvailable = false;
                // Get a stream object for reading
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (!dataAvailable)
                    {
                        dataAvailable = stream.DataAvailable;
                        //Console.WriteLine("Data Available: "+dataAvailable);
                        if (server.Pending())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("found new client");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (dataAvailable)
                    {
                        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                        i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
                        dataAvailable = false;
                    }

                    if (server.Pending())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("found new client");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Client close");
                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            Console.WriteLine("Stop listening for new clients.");
            server.Stop();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are in your inner `while` loop, you can't check for new connections. So you would have to add something like this inside the loop:

```
if ( server.Pending() ) break;
```

That will exit your loop as soon as another connection is waiting.

Another problem is that `stream.Read` will block until some data is available, so new connections will not get handled if the active one is idle. So you have to change it, and not call `Read` unless there is some data, using `stream.DataAvailable`

Comment: After a bit struggle, I managed to get it all to work thanks to your solution! I appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm using and it's working pretty good so far, I've just started working on this type of application. If I make any significant changes or find bugs with this code I'll update:

```
class ClientListener
{
    const int PORT_NO = 4500;
    const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private TcpListener listener;

    public async Task Listen()
    {
        IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
        listener = new TcpListener(localAddress, PORT_NO);
        Console.WriteLine("Listening on: " + SERVER_IP + ":" + PORT_NO);
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            // Accept incoming connection that matches IP / Port number
            // We need some form of security here later
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

            if (client.Connected)
            {
                // Get the stream of data send by the server and create a buffer of data we can read
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                // Convert the data recieved into a string
                string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved Data: " + data);
            }
        }
    }

    public void StopListening()
    {
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```