# TCP/IP Continuously receive message without closing the connection

Tags: c#, tcp

I've been watching the following pair of videos on how to create a TCP/IP connection : [Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXFso7xSSWk&t=505s&index=1&list=PLlYbu_LkjKS7Rlvy0TUx60XPTqH7idn36)  and [Client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NanjpGKC2js&list=PLlYbu_LkjKS7Rlvy0TUx60XPTqH7idn36&index=2)
What I need to do is create a game (flipcard) in which I send only 2 coordinates for a matrix. Nothing more. Or less.

(the code will follow)

From what I've observed, he closes and reopens the connection, everytime he send a message. It's working. But what do I **modify in the code to keep the connection** open and **detect when a message arrived** ?

All my google-searches brought me to these 2 methods:

1. [I have had luck using the socket object directly (rather than the TCP client).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3609784/6063416)  (But I do not want to use sockets)
2. [Also uses sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262806/tcp-send-multiple-message-without-closing-connection)

**When I click to start the server**

```
        private void bStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread tcpServerRunThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TCPServerRun));
        tcpServerRunThread.Start();
    }
```

**Server Runs and waits for a connection**

```
    private void TCPServerRun()
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2016);
        tcpListener.Start();
        updateUI("Listening");
        while (true)
        {

            TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            updateUI("Connected");
            Thread tcpHandlerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(tcpHandler));
            tcpHandlerThread.Start(client);
        }
    }
```

**I handle my message**

```
    private void tcpHandler(object client)
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5004);
        TcpClient mClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream stream =  mClient.GetStream();
        byte[] message = new byte[1024];
        stream.Read(message,0, message.Length);
        updateUI("New message = " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message));
        stream.Close();
        mClient.Close();
   }
```

**NOTE**: `updateUI` is a function made by him to update a listbox item

**Client side** - almost like the server side
    `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread mThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ConnectAsClient));
            mThread.Start();
        }

```
    private void ConnectAsClient()
    {
        //                 aici putem inlocui cu adresa de IP dorita             
        //client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(textBox.Text), 5004);
        client = new TcpClient();
        //client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2016);     // for when I'm not connected to network
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("my_ip_here"), 2016);   // for when I am connected to the network
        updateUI("connected");
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        string s = "Hello world!";
        byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
        this.updateUI("Message sent!");
       stream.Close();
       // client.Close();
    }`
```

If I'm not wrong, everytime he connects again, he creates a new connection, and not open the old one, right?
(It's my first time using TCP/IP, learning on my own, so I'd rather not use sockets, if possible)

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------**

Full link to my code (slighty modified from the videos provided at the beginning):

1. [TCPClient](http://pastebin.com/mwPgbVqk)
2. [TCPServer](http://pastebin.com/n24pve6J)

Comment: you do not need to close it. but if I remember right you need to send a response message to the client before you can receive the next message

Answer (score 0):

You are reconnecting every time you send the message. Use two different methods for this; one for connecting to the server and then another one for actually sending the message. Like so:

```c#
TcpClient client;
private void ConnectAsClient()
{           
    //client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(textBox.Text), 5004);
    client = new TcpClient();
    //client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2016);
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("my_ip_here"), 2016);
    updateUI("connected");
}
void SendMessage()
{
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    string s = "Hello world!";
    byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
    this.updateUI("Message sent!");
}
```

Comment: And how do I detect when my message arrived ?

Comment: in the "tcpHandler" method its already set up. It will freeze on the line "stream.Read(..." untill it recieves a message.