# How to reset a stream?

Tags: c#, stream, lis, interfacing, astm

I am trying to connect a pathology analyzer and receive data. Following is my code.

```
private void ReceiveData(string IP, string PortNo)
        {
            var port = Convert.ToInt32(PortNo);
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            byte ACK = 6;
            byte[] ACK_BUFF = { ACK };
            try
            {
                server.Start();
                var bytes = new byte[1024];
                string data = string.Empty;
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                using (Stream stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int i;
                        i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            if (chkBidirectional_NI.Checked)
                                stream.Write(ACK_BUFF, 0, ACK_BUFF.Length);
                            string line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                            if (i > 1)
                            {
                                data += line;
                               
                            }
                            if (data.IndexOf("L|1|N") > -1)
                                ReceiveDataSJH(data);
                        }                                               
                    }                    
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thrNoti = new Thread(() => ReceiveData(txtIPAddress___.Text, txtPortNo___.Text));
            thrNoti.Start();
            
        }
```

Above code is working fine but each time I have to start the program again because `stream` disposes. 
How can I reset my program so it ready again to receive data ?
**Update:-** Maybe my question is wrong. The main issue is my program stops working after one transfer. 
**Update2:-** I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387086/how-to-set-up-tcplistener-to-always-listen-and-accept-multiple-connections/26562695#26562695) thread. But it's about handling multiple connections at the same time. According to the answer of that thread when I am putting  `using (Stream stream = client.GetStream())` inside `while` loop analyzer says `LIS is not responding`.
Maybe I'm wrong but I think when machine stops sending data `stream` object disposes because it's by `using`. So my program stops receiving data after some time.
Please suggest me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user246821 Is it a good idea to receive data without `stream`? This question is doing so.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26562695/10024425 (also see the last comment).

Comment: Having read the question, I now see why it was down-voted. There's no logic to "resetting" that stream. You either need to keep getting data from the same stream or you need to create a new stream. We don't know which of those is appropriate because you haven't really provided enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `while` loop here, so you're on the right track; however, you should treat `i <= 0` as an EOF condition and *exit* rather than keep looping forever; `Stream.Read` returning a non-positive value means EOF (with a slight caveat around zero-length reads, but you're not doing a zero-length read, so don't worry about that).

The next thing we need to think about is text encoding; I don't know the protocol details of this API, but your `line =` logic *isn't actually valid* for UTF8, because you *could* have bytes from the same character split over multiple reads - necessitating more complex read logic. If the data is actually ASCII then it is much simpler, and that logic is valid. Streams are not message based, so *usually* you should have some kind of "framing" logic *before* you try parsing any data; this could be "keep buffering bytes until we see a CR+LF". If you post details (or a link) of the expected protocol, I may be able to help more (stream protocol parsing is something I do *a lot*).

There's also what looks like a bug where if the data trickles in one byte at a time, you drop `line` on the floor each time without ever handling any of it. Again this would be fixed by appropriate "framing" and buffering until an entire frame can be processed. I should emphasize: you might find zero, one or multiple complete frames plus maybe an incomplete frame after any read operation - depending on how the network transmits the incoming data.

But it looks like you're not far off here, assuming this is actually a multi-message streaming protocol. It doesn't make sense to reset/rewind this kind of stream: you simply can't - you get one shot at handling the data, and then it is gone forever (hence *you* need to handle any backlog buffering if you can't process an entire frame yet).

Note that for many simple text-based protocols, you might be able to subcontract all the thinking to `StreamReader`, and just use `ReadLine()` until it returns `null` (which signifies EOF). However, this should be done with some caution, as `StreamReader` cannot enforce quotas for you to protect against malign payloads (for example, feeding you a constant stream of text without any line breaks). This is probably more of a concern if you're the server than the client.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. When machine is sending data in real time it's sending multiple frames and there is no difference between frames so I am unable to pick to EOF. So I am transferring data to my software on each frame. 
But that's not the main issue my program stop receiving data after first transmission. Can you please suggest where am I doing wrong. Also check my update.
Can I please communicate with you with mail if you don't mind? I am in big trouble.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi the frame (individual messages) need to be defined *somehow*, since TCP isn't a message protocol (but rather: a stream protocol). I was mistaken in my first glance, though: it looks like you are the server not the client, which means you need to be a *lot* more careful - this will scale to 1 concurrent client as written, and will be easy to stall. Plus the UTF8 etc issues. Without appropriate frames, you're not ACKing correctly. But: I'm easy to get hold of via email (see the profile tab on my user page).

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi note that you *do* need some kind of loop exit after EOF - at the moment you loop forever once a socket breaks, but this needs to be applied *alongside* proper deframing and decoding; happy to advice further, but knowledge of he actual protocol would really help here.

Comment: I have already tried exit loop after EOF but that time I don't know how to restart program again. Should I call the program again after exit the loop?

Comment: I don't know why my program stops receiving data after first communication. Can you please help?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi I almost certainly can, but I need a *lot* more context; not least: more detail of the data protocol / framing; as a server, making it service concurrent clients is also *very* important, generally, but *in some cases* it doesn't matter - but you still definitely need to exit the loop at some point, otherwise you app will just hang; it looks like your "server" is a windows UI app, which is *unusual* but might be valid, if this is a single-client scenario. But let's focus on the protocol part; we need to deframe *properly* to ACK at the correct times; is there a link?

Comment: I mailed you the protocol pdf on given mail in your profile.